# How to use extend among scss selector functions

Tags: css, sass

( Please understand that I am using a translator as I do not speak English. )

When using scss, there are times when you need to use the same properties. So at that time, I would like to process it with an if statement. please help me!!! T.T
( There is also a way to do it using @mixin, but I want another way.... )

1. How do we know that css has a .parent?

```
#child, .parent #child{
    $color:'';
    $colorRGB:'';

    @if #{selector.is-superselector("#{&}", "parent")}{
        $color:'255';
    } @else {
        $color:'0';

    $colorRGB: $color + ', ' + $color + ', ' + $color;
    border:solid #{'rgba(#{$colorRGB}, 0.3)'}; 
}
```

2. Below is an example of the scss official document. I wonder why .guide is included after .content.
   https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/selector/#replace

```
@debug selector.replace(".guide .info", ".info", ".content nav.sidebar");
// .guide .content nav.sidebar, .content .guide nav.sidebar
```

3. Is there a function that returns the sum of itself and other selectors when selecting a selector?
   What I want: when (a, b) the return value is (a, .b .a)
   Something similar is okay!

..

1. @debug #{selector.is-superselector("#{&}", ".parent #{&}")};

- I couldn't branch because it returned true every time.

2. @debug selector.extend(" #child", " ", ".parent");

- I couldn't use it because the grammar was wrong.